# Binding of a button click command in c#

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism-4

I have a following piece of XAML which binds a button click using prism. Can someone guide how can I achieve the same behavior in code behind since I need to create the button dynamically? Thanks.

```
 <telerik:RadButton Margin="2"
                    TabIndex="3"
                    prism:Click.Command="{Binding cmdNew}">
```

**EDIT :**  One thing I missed to mention in my post was that these command names are stored in database and I need to generate these command objects on the fly. So in this case if "cmdNew" was stored in db and I had to bind it dynamically to the button how would I go about doing that? I have looked at DelegateCommand but not sure if that can be helpful in this scenario. Your response is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a good idea : have a unique command `MyButton.Command = MyDbCmd;` and use command parameter as switch `MyButton.CommandParameter = "dbvalue";` ?

Comment: Hmm, may be it is. But for once do you have an idea if following getter / setter code can be generated dynamically? public ICommand cmdNew { get; set; }

Answer (score 2):

```
Click.SetCommand(button, <value>)
```

Comment: [Radbuttons](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radbuttons-features-commands.html) have command property, you can set directly `MyButton.Command = cmdNew;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the event (I think it is called) Click = "NameOfMethod" ), where NameOfMethod is a method in your cs file belonging to the screen.

When the button is clicked, the method NameOfMethod will be called.

Comment: This is not triggering the method in the ViewModel, but rather searching for the method in the code-behind. Or did I get your answer wrong? Could you provide sample code?